# FunctionInterpolation and Which combine badly

Tags: interpolation, logic

Update 2: Got two solid answers, but had trouble implementing one, and found the other could only save me computation time by sacrificing accuracy. So I chose neither as an official answer, but they're both worth looking at if you're trying to interpolate a "sharp" (not smooth) function.

Update: The main question has been answered, but my problem hasn't been solved. The problem is I have a situation where I want to use Which on an InterpolatingFunction several times to repeatedly "fold" the function. But I'm finding that as soon as I nest Which even once (i.e. use a Which'd function for both values of a new Which call), I get a slow down when using the resulting function of >300%. I can find no other explanation for the slowing down. So I'm attempting to turn the first Which into an InterpolatingFunction to simplify the final function. Any suggestions on a better solution?

---

I define these two functions:

```
x1 = FunctionInterpolation[Sin[t], {t, 0, 20}];
x2 = FunctionInterpolation[
   Which[x1[t] >= 0, x1[t], x1[t] < 0, -x1[t]], {t, 0, 20}];
```

and find that the latter gives a bizarre, incorrect function:

```
Plot[x1[t], {t, 0, 20}]
Plot[x2[t], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1}]
```

[image: plot of x1[t]]
[image: plot of x2[t]]

The problem is that the second graph should look like the absolute value of the first. I'm trying to understand why the combination of FunctionInterpolation -> Which -> FunctionInterpolation has this effect so I can fix it.

My actual code is more complex than this (this is just a reduced sample case), so workarounds specific to this case wouldn't be very helpful. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: It probably has trouble with those kinks at `y==0`. `Abs[Sin[t]]` does better.

Comment: Ah I think you're right. Can you suggest a way to get an interpolating function that allows those kinds of kinks?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. Why do you need it? Can you use `Which` *outside* the `InterpolatingFunction`? That is, interpolate the smooth function first (which will work nicely), then take the absolute value (or whatever it is you need to do) afterward.

Comment: I have a situation where I want to use Which on an InterpolatingFunction several times to repeatedly "fold" the function. But I'm finding that as soon as I nest Which even once (i.e. use a Which'd function for both values of a new Which call), I get a slow down when using the resulting function of >300%. I can find no other explanation for the slowing down. So I'm attempting to turn the first Which into an InterpolatingFunction to simplify the final function. Any suggestions on a better solution?

Comment: I can't think of a way, but other people may chime in.

Comment: Try `PiecewiseExpand` on the `Which` statements to see if you can avoid interpolating.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oddly enough that ended up making my program slower. I think by expanding out the Which's it just made the function bulkier? Seemed like a promising idea though.

Comment: @Max It's hard to speculate without a truly representative example to analyze.  It might be that `x2[t_?NumericQ] := With[{y = x1[t]}, Which[y >= 0, y, y < 0, -y]]` would solve the problem, by reducing the number of times `x1[t]` is computed. Depending on how your "folding" is computed, that might be easy to implement or it might take some thought.  Hard to say without a good example to work on.

Answer (score 8):

Protecting the expression with `NumericQ` works, too.

```
x1 = FunctionInterpolation[Sin[t], {t, 0., 20.}];
x2n[t_?NumericQ] := Which[x1[t] >= 0, x1[t], x1[t] < 0, -x1[t]];
x2 = FunctionInterpolation[x2n[t], {t, 0., 20.}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 15, AccuracyGoal -> 5];

Plot[x2[t], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Addendum:** To increase accuracy, the accuracy of all computations need to be increased, including `x1`.

```
x1 = FunctionInterpolation[Sin[t], {t, 0., 20.}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 11, MaxRecursion -> 25];
x2n[t_?NumericQ] := Which[x1[t] >= 0, x1[t], x1[t] < 0, -x1[t]];
x2 = FunctionInterpolation[x2n[t], {t, 0., 20.}, MaxRecursion -> 35, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 11];

Plot[x2[t] - Abs[Sin[t]], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Doesn't  work on V9 ;(

Comment: @belisarius D'oh. Misedited the code. Should work now.

Comment: Much better +1:) It looked odd, indeed. BTW, don't you wonder how a wrong answer gets upvoted ?

Comment: @belisarius All the time. :)  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I need higher accuracy than 5, preferably around 10 or more. Do you know a way to push up the accuracy of FunctionInterpolation (besides just changing AccuracyGoal, which doesn't work here)?

Comment: Specifically I'm aiming to minimize Plot[x2[t] - Abs[Sin[t]], {t, 0, 20}], which currently won't push past 10^-6

Comment: @Max You probably can't expect to do better than the input `x1`: `Plot[x1[t] - Sin[t], {t, 0, 20}]`. Max error > 10^-6, RMS errror 4 * 10^-7.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Your addendum was helpful, but when trying to implement your method in my full code it always returns an error that it can't reach the requested accuracy. I've tried decreasing the accuracy and precision, increasing MaxRecursion, and ensuring that my (more complicated) "x1" really is accurate/precise enough, but to no avail. The fault may very well be my own somehow, but I've decided to give up for the moment. Thanks anyway for the help!

Comment: @Max You're welcome.  Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

You may use the [**unlinkedly documented**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolationPoints.html) option `InterpolationPoints`

```
x1 = FunctionInterpolation[Sin[t], {t, 0, 20},  InterpolationPoints -> 1000];
x2 = FunctionInterpolation[ Which[x1[t] >= 0, x1[t], x1[t] < 0, -x1[t]], {t, 0, 20}, 
                           InterpolationPoints -> 1000];
Plot[x2[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

These are the Options for `FunctionInterpolation`:

```
Options[FunctionInterpolation]

{InterpolationOrder->3,
 InterpolationPrecision->Automatic,
 AccuracyGoal->Automatic,
 PrecisionGoal->Automatic,
 InterpolationPoints->11,
 MaxRecursion->6}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get better accuracy on this but with little success. Using (InterpolationPoints -> 10000, AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10, InterpolationPrecision -> 10), I still can't get past an error of ~10^-7 for Plot[x2[t] - Abs[Sin[t]], {t, 0, 20}]. Any thoughts on making this more accurate?

Comment: @Max Are you setting those options in both Interplations? How are you measuring the error? Can you post that code?

Comment: `x1 = FunctionInterpolation[ Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   InterpolationPoints -> 10000];
x2 = FunctionInterpolation[
   Which[x1[t] >= 0, x1[t], x1[t] < 0, -x1[t]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   InterpolationPoints -> 10000];
Plot[x2[t] - Abs[Sin[t]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All]` gives me `10^-15` (MachinePrecision)

Comment: You were right, I hadn't realized I would need to use InterpolationPoints on my initial function too (you may want to add that to your post). However I'm finding that to get my desired accuracy I need at least InterpolationPoints->10000, and that requirement takes so long that my code ends up even slower than it started. I really liked your idea, but seems it didn't work out for my purposes. Thanks for the help though!